# Need to Store data into Azure Data lake Store using Azure Stream Analytics and IoT Hub: Data must be stored by 4MB buffer

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-iot-hub, azure-stream-analytics

I need to Store data into Aure Data lake Store using Azure Stream Analytics and IoT Hub. I configured my input and my output in Azure stream Analytics, and wrote my query:

```
SELECT * INTO [output-ADLS] FROM [inputForIotHub]
```

It works fine and get my data in my data lake store. However, now I need that my streamed data **must be stored by 4MB buffer** for performance issues: I store my streamed data into [output-ADLS] each time I have 4MB as input data.

Any help please ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

ASA will try to batch events together up to 4MB to minimize the number of transactions. However if the frequency of incoming events is low, ASA will keep smaller batches to ensure lower latency.
It is not possible today to manually tune this, but we can think about adding this to the roadmap.